# Unicode character not recognized

Tags: c++, unicode, character, wxwidgets

I'm creating a C++ wxWidgets application. I have this code:

```
buttons.push_back(L"\u221A");
buttons.push_back(L"\u207F\u221A");
```

Where `buttons` is:

```
std::vector<wxString> buttons;
```

[image: Unicode characters not recognized]

The button to the left displays the square root character correctly. The right one is supposed to be an nth-root, but the apex n character isn't recognized and therefore replaced by a ? mark.

To display the symbols on the button I just set the text in the constructor:

```
// aggiungi pulsanti
grid = new wxGridSizer(r, c, 0, 0);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
{
    expandButton* btn = new expandButton(this, wxID_ANY, buttons.at(i), size);
    if (label == buttons.at(i)) btn->SetSelected(true);
    grid->Add(btn, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 2);
}
```

I'm using MSVS 2019 if it helps in any way.

Comment: Does the font that you are using support that character?

Comment: The font is Lato, and I don't know. How do I check?

Comment: You can use charmap to check if a font contains a certain character.  Select Unicode from the "Character set:" dropdown, and then enter "207F" in the "Go to Uincode" text box.  That shows that the character is available in the Lato font, so the problem must be something else.

Comment: Can you show the code where you draw the n-th root symbol.

Comment: Yes, I'm editing the post right now

Comment: Anyways, I don't know if this means something, but if I look up for 207F in the char map [I can't seem to find the apex n character](https://pasteboard.co/K85LuRm.png).

Comment: I guess different versions of windows have different versions of fonts.  I  did not know that.  So I guess you'll either need to use another symbol that is in the font, use another font that does have the symbol, or use an image instead of text.

Comment: Nevermind, I just changed the font to Arial, and it works now.